# How to change url for taxonomy pages?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

My Wordpress default category has 'news' category term. I created custom post type with name 'artist' and custom taxonomy named 'genre'. Now what I set in permalink section is below

```
custom structure - /news/%category%/%postname%/
```

because I want to open all my default post open with 'news' slug. I create page taxonomy-genre.php which lead to all post of genre taxonomy. let say genre taxonpmy has term 'afro-pop'. Now when I view the page it display all post of 'afro-pop' but problem is that it has url

```
http://localhost/mn2s-new/news/genre/afro-pop/
```

what I want is

```
http://localhost/mn2s-new/genre/afro-pop/
```

I want to remove that news slug for taxonomy-genre.php page. Please help me with this I am trying from 2 days but doesn't find any solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled by the `with_front` argument in your taxonomy registration code:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'genre',
    'artist',
    array(
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'genre',
            'with_front' => false, // don't prepend static prefix from post permalink
        ),
        // your other args...
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I knew about it but I was trying complicated method like generate_rewrite rule. but u saved my day. thanks a lot. I don't have enough reputation to vote  u up but when I will get enough reputation I will definitely do it. thanks thanks thanks